# Flutter pdf package not able to split single column into pages

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a PDF using the pdf package.

My issue is that the current PDF I need to generate now has several rows and columns with text that may not fit in the free available space inside the generated A4 page and moves the row/column to the next page.

Here you have the code I am using to show the texts,that are loaded into a listview:

```
static Widget buildTablaDiario(List<dynamic> listaDiarioActual) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listaDiarioActual.length,
        itemBuilder: (pw.Context context, index) {
          DiarioModelo diario = listaDiarioActual[index];

          DateTime tempDateI =
              new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(diario.fecha_diario);

          String date1 = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(tempDateI);
          String hora = DateFormat("HH:mm").format(tempDateI);
          return Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      pw.Text("${hora}", style: pw.TextStyle()),
                      pw.SizedBox(width: 10),
                      pw.Container(
                        width: 320,
                        child: pw.Text(diario.descripcion),
                      ),
                      pw.SizedBox(height: 15)
                    ]);



        });

  }
```

And here you have a couple of screenshots from the generated PDF:

[image]

[image]

[image]